# How to make a div like bootstrap popup with css in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a table whose data is coming from loop,Here a 'click here' link is there when you click the link a div will open with position absolute,This div I want to make like bootstrap modal with css. If it is fine with bootstrap its ok. When you press close button popup should close like bootstrap.Here is the code below

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvwuqz

### app.component.html

```
<table class="table border">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns; let i = index">
        <th>{{ column }}</th>
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of groups;let i = index">
            <td>{{row.name}}</td>
            <td>{{row.items}}</td>
            <td>{{row.Status.length}}-<span (click)="hideme[i] = true" style="border:1px solid;" >Click here</span>
               <div style="position:absolute;top:10px;border:1px solid;padding:20px;position:absolute;background:#fff;" [hidden]="!hideme[i]"> <span  *ngFor="let item of row.Status;let j = index">
                    {{item.name}}
                    <span *ngIf="j != row.Status.length - 1">,</span></span><span (click)="hideme[i] = false" style="position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;cursor:pointer;">close</span></div>
           </td>
            <td>
                <span *ngFor="let item of row.loc;let k = index">
                   {{item.name}}
                   <span *ngIf="k != row.loc.length - 1">,</span>
                </span>     
           </td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
selectedRow : Number;
 name = 'Angular';
 selectedgroup: any;
 hideme=[];

columns = ["name", "Items","status", "loc"];

  groups=[{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "pencils",
        "items": "red pencil",
        "Status": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "green"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "red"
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "yellow"
        }],
        "loc": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "loc 1"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "loc 2"
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "loc 3"
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "rubbers",
        "items": "big rubber",
        "Status": [{

            "name": "green"
        }, {

            "name": "red"
        }],
        "loc": [{

            "name": "loc 2"
        }, {

            "name": "loc 3"
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "rubbers1",
        "items": "big rubber1",
        "Status": [{

            "name": "green"
        }, {

            "name": "red"
        }],
        "loc": [{

            "name": "loc 2"
        }, {

            "name": "loc 3"
        }]
    }

];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code Can Be Tested On: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wrwdov)

Got some code from W3Schools and also added 2 javascript functions which accept a index. code is self explanatory.

**app.component.html**

```
<table class="table border">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns; let i = index">
        <th>{{ column }}</th>
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of groups;let i = index">
            <td>{{row.name}}</td>
            <td>{{row.items}}</td>
            <td>{{row.Status.length}}-<span (click)="displayBox(i)" style="border:1px solid;" >Click here</span>
               <div  class="modal" id="model_{{i}}" style="display:none;">
                  <div class="modal-content"> 
                    <span (click)="closeBox(i)" class="close">&times;</span>
                  <span *ngFor="let item of row.Status;let j = index">
                    {{item.name}}
                    <span *ngIf="j != row.Status.length - 1">,</span>
                  </span>
                </div>
                </div>
           </td>
            <td>
                <span *ngFor="let item of row.loc;let k = index">
                   {{item.name}}
                   <span *ngIf="k != row.loc.length - 1">,</span>
                </span>     
           </td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
selectedRow : Number;
 name = 'Angular';
 selectedgroup: any;
 hideme=[];

columns = ["name", "Items","status", "loc"];

  groups=[{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "pencils",
        "items": "red pencil",
        "Status": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "green"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "red"
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "yellow"
        }],
        "loc": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "loc 1"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "loc 2"
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "loc 3"
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "rubbers",
        "items": "big rubber",
        "Status": [{

            "name": "green"
        }, {

            "name": "red"
        }],
        "loc": [{

            "name": "loc 2"
        }, {

            "name": "loc 3"
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "rubbers1",
        "items": "big rubber1",
        "Status": [{

            "name": "green"
        }, {

            "name": "red"
        }],
        "loc": [{

            "name": "loc 2"
        }, {

            "name": "loc 3"
        }]
    }

];

  displayBox(index:number):void{
    var modal = document.getElementById("model_" + index);
    modal.style.display = 'block';
  }

  closeBox(index:number):void{
    var modal = document.getElementById("model_" + index);
    modal.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

**app.component.css**

```
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}


/*
* Code from: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp
*/

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Good Luck with your project.